# Looking to build a new PC

Tags: modeling, rendering

I'm looking to build a new PC. I'm a product design student using Solidworks, Fusion and Rhino for 3D modeling as Well as Blender and keyshot for rendering/animation. I was given a quote about a PC which parts I'm listing below. I'm just getting started with hardcore modeling/rendering, but I plan on doing it for the next few years. Could you guys tell me if this build is good for everything I need, or some advice on what to get instead? Thx in advance

CPU AMD RYZEN 7 7700X

NOCTUA NH-L9A-AM5

MB ASUS PRIME B650-PLUS B650 AM5 4XDDR5DC-6400(OC) DP HDMI 1XPCIE4.0X16 4XSATA3 M.2 USB3.2 ATX

32GB DDR5 4800MHZ KINGSTON

CASE MIDI ATX

POWER SUPPLY ATX ASUS TUF-GAMING-750B 80+ BRONZE 750W VENTOLA-135MM PFC ATTIVO

SSD-SOLID STATE DISK M.2(2280) NVME 1000GB (1TB) PCIE4.0X4 CRUCIAL P5 PLUS CT1000P5PSSD8 READ:6600MB/S-WRITE:5000MB/S

SVGA ASUS TUF-RTX4070TI-O12G-GAMING 12GBDDR6X PCIE4.0 192BIT 2XHDMI 3XDP HDCP-2.3 7680X4320 3,25SLOT

W11H

EURO 2200

Comment: In the [Hardware Unboxed review](https://youtu.be/DTFUa60ozKY?feature=shared&t=742), the Asus Prime B650-Plus board had really high VRM temperatures. Maybe choose another one.